# LWJGL GUI not starting

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics, lwjgl

I am trying to get into LWGJL and Game development. I am trying to make a basic window but nothing is showing up. I imported LWJGL and Slick. Also, do you know of any good Java game development tutorials? Thanks for the help!

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
 import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
 import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
 import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

 public class Boot {
  public void Boot() {
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(600,400));
        Display.create();
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 600, 400, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    // init OpenGL here

    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
         glBegin(GL_LINES);
         glVertex2f(10, 10);
         glVertex2f(100, 100);
         glEnd();
        // render OpenGL here

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
    }

    Display.destroy();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   new Boot();


     }
 }
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `glClear()` call before you start drawing.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with LWJGL with this tutorial...
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0S5Ded2IJY

That's how I started ;)
It's pretty much step-by-step tut... so you can figure everything out easily

Answer (score 0):

You probably intended for that method named `Boot` to be a constructor.
`public void Boot` should be changed to `public Boot`.